# Nautilus hangs 18.04

Tags: 18.04, nautilus

I have been using Ubuntu for years; generally it is extremely stable, I usually run the LTS versions. However the most common thing that takes my system down is issues around nautilus; today everything was going fine and nautilus just hung.

Nothing special was happening; I was trying to access my Downloads folder. I thought that maybe my network share (Ubuntu server 18.04) was causing issues but I couldn't unmount the share as it was "busy". Nautilus refused to be ended, stopped or killed; eventually I gave up and rebooted my laptop (System 76 Oryx pro) this required me to shutdown various VM's and other programs first.

This is not a frequent issue but when it occurs it is extremely annoying.

Other times nautilus will refuse to open my home folder but will happily open `~/Documents`, `~/Downloads` etc..

Today was particularly bad as usually I can kill nautilus and restart it.

I run a pretty much stock Ubuntu as stability is extremely important to me; does anyone know what causes these issues with nautilus and how to avoid them?

Note: browsing files via terminal is never affected when nautilus is giving me issues.

Note2: this has occurred on various computers over the years; Alienware M15x; Asus Zenbook UX32VD.

Comment: Can the network share be unmounted from the command line? If not it might reveal error messages you couldn't see with Nautilus.

Comment: No I usually unmount the share when not using it via terminal; but was unable this time.

Comment: Today Nautilus is at it again. I can't open a window without it crashing.

Comment: I have no networked drives. I still see this problem. I've seen it on different machines ranging from a i7 laptop to a server with a RAID.  The busy symbol in Nautilus is small which I think creates confusion because normally I am browsing around quickly and the spinning circle is easy to miss.